# Trouble echoing contents of a folder - Batch script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a directory which contains only binary files(*.elf).

I need to perform some operation in each of the file.

```
for /D %G in (%VAR%\DIR\*) do ( echo %G )
```

Above command doesn't echo the contents of DIR. In fact it doesn't give me anything.

Answer (score 0):

This will echo each filename - there are gotcha's when changing files using the same filetype.  Only you know what you are doing in the loop.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.elf) do echo %%a
```

Comment: I have used the exact command. But i don't see any output in the command prompt.

Comment: It is a batch file.  Launch it in the folder with the files, and place a `pause` as the last line if you are clicking on it.

Comment: if you're using just the command prompt, use this `for %a in (*.elf) do echo %a`

Comment: Here is my code in the batch file

    @echo off

    for /D %%G in (*.elf) do (
  pause
  echo %%G
  )
    )

I am still not able to see anything echoed on the command prompt when i run this